# Proving the exponential properties of the fundamental matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been taking a class in differential equations and recentily encountered the fundamental matrix. I also watched some YouTube videos about the subject and saw that it can also be understood with exponential matrixes. This has to mean that the fundamental matrix possess exponential properties. I want to show this but im stuck, how do you show that the fundamental matrix (A) behaves like an exponential function, i.e. show that:
$
A(t)(s) = A(T+S),
A(t)A(-t) = I
$
etc. when I is the identity matrix.

Comment: First define the "fundamental matrix".

Comment: What is the fundamental matrix?